# What is the maximum memory per worker that MATLAB can address?

Tags: matlab, ram, multicore, worker

**Short version:** Is there a maximum amount of RAM / worker, that MATLAB can address?

**Long version:** My wife uses MATLAB's parallel processing capabilities in data-heavy spatial analyses (I don't really understand it, I just know how to build computers that make her work quicker) and I would like to build a new computer so she can radically reduce her process times.

I am leaning toward something in the 10-16 core range, since prices on such processors seem to be dropping with each generation and I would like to use 128 GB of RAM, because 'why not' if you can stomach the cost and see some meaningful time savings?

The number of cores I shoot for will depend on the maximum amount of RAM that MATLAB can address for each worker (if such a limit exists). The computer I built for similar work in 2013 has 4 physical cores (Intel i7-3770k) and 32 GB RAM (which she maxed out), and whatever I build next, I would like to have at least the same memory/core. With 128 GB of RAM a given, 10 cores would be 12.8 GB/core, 12 cores would be ~10.5 GB/core and 16 cores would be 8 GB/core. I am inclined to maximize cores rather than memory, but since she doesn't know what will benefit her processes the most, I would like to know how realistic those three options are. As for your next question, she has an nVidia GPU capable of parallel processing, but she believes her processes would not benefit from its CUDA cores.

Thank you for your insights. Many, many Google searches did not yield an answer.

Comment: Once having entered into a realm of 64-bit addressing, your wife's enemy is not the theoretical size of the address-space, but it's actual performance. If she is indeed in data-intensive computations, the latency-costs of the flow of data are way more important, than anything else. While you can buy many toys, based on marketing bells & whistles, the most efficient [FLOPS/co$t$] would come from more insights than from a [GB/core] ratio. Best consult with some HPC expert before spending your wife's hardware budget in a popular, but rather performance-agnostic naive way.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. My interpretation of your response is that there is no limit to the GB of RAM / worker. Is that correct? Perhaps I phrased my original question incorrectly/imprecisely, but that is ultimately what I would like to know.

Comment: user3666197, Is my interpretation of your comment correct? I was hoping for something along the lines of 'No, there is no limit' or 'Yes, the limit is XGB/worker', but I thought I might be able to interpret your feedback. If my interpretation is incorrect I hope you'll set me straight. Thank you.